# How do I insert one to many relational multi data to same table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

My table structure is: 
id | parent_id | name. 
My Menu model one to many relationship is:

```
          public function childMenus() { 
          return $this->hasMany( ‘App\Menu’, ’parent_id’); 
          } 

         public function parentMenus() {
         return $this->belongsTo(‘App\Menu’, ‘parent_id’); 
         }
```

I am creating menus with sub menus.For example I have to set 'Parent Menu' with three child menus.For this I have created a form with four inputs field.

```
<form>
     <input type="text" name="parent">
     <input type="text" name="child[]">
     <input type="text" name="child[]">
     <input type="text" name="child[]">
     </form>
```

Now I want to save parent menu with its child menus at the same time.I tried to save them in array but its not working in Laravel.
Please also explain what would be the controller method for saving this data.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you create the main menu and save it , you create the sub menu and save it (->save()) the you take the submenu id and attach it to main menu , `$mainmenu->childMenus()->attach($submenu->id);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `saveMany` method to attach multiple children to a parent.

```
// Assuming whatever goes into the text box goes in the "name" field.
$parent = new \App\Parent();
$parent->name = \Input::get('name');
$parent->save();

$children = [];
foreach (Input::get('child') as $child) {
    $children = new \App\Child([
        'name' => $child
    ]);
}

$parent->childMenus()->saveMany($children);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my question.Here I am posting...

```
    $parent_menu = $request->input('parent');
    $parent = Menu::create(['name' =>  $parent_menu]);
    $parent->save();
    $child_menus = $request->input('child');
    foreach($child_menus as $child_menu) {
    $child = $parent->pages()->create(['name' => $child_menu]);
    $child->save();
    }
```